# JavaScript function date.getMonth() not retrieving the correct month number? (11 instead of 8)

Tags: javascript, function, date

So first of all this is not about getMonth returning numbers from 0-11 instead of 1-12, and sorry for my english.

I wanted to make a simple program to display the current date on the browser, like "September is the month, 26 is the day, 2016 is the year". I did this:

```
!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="test"></p>               // this is where date will be displayed
    <script>
        var date = new Date();      // i get the date 
        var m = date.getMonth();    // i get the month
        var fm;                     // all this is to convert number to month name
        if (m=0){fm="January";}
        if (m=1){fm="February";}
        if (m=2){fm="March";}
        if (m=3){fm="April";}
        if (m=4){fm="May";}
        if (m=5){fm="Jun";}
        if (m=6){fm="July";}
        if (m=7){fm="August";}
        if (m=8){fm="September";}
        if (m=9){fm="October";}
        if (m=10){fm="November";}
        if (m=11){fm="December";}
        else {fm="Error01"}
        var d = date.getDate();      // the day
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= fm + " is the month, " + d + " is the Date(day) and "+ y + " is the full year"; 
        // i removed this ^ to highlight the new output below:
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= date + "<br>" + m + " - " + fm;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

At This point the output should be:

> Mon Sep 26 2016 23:38:39 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)
>
> 8 - September

("Ora legale Europa occidentale" = my local time, it shouldn't be relevant here).

But for some reasons, this is what i get when i run the program:

> Mon **Sep** 26 2016 23:38:39 GMT+0200 (ora legale Europa occidentale)
>
> 11 - December

Month is correct in the date (says "Sept"), but wrong in the other output (m="11" which causes var fm to be "December")
Why?? :(

Comment: All your `if(m=xx)` statements are assigning instead of comparing. Should be: `if(m===xx)`

Comment: That is, `m=0` sets `m` to `0` and returns that `0`. However `m==0` (or `m === 0)` tests if the variable `m` is set to `0`

Comment: Ohh yea thanks! Solved

Comment: I would use a switch statement here instead of a bunch of ifs.

Comment: You need to use `else if`, or else the last `else` only applies to `m==11`. Also, use two equal signs.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg I would use a [direct array lookup](http://phrogz.net/js/FormatDateTime_JS.txt) for simplicity and speed. Frederico, that code may also help you to more simply format your date/times in the future.

Comment: @Phrogz Yep. Good point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `==` not `=`; `=` is assigning and `==` is comparing.

However, you can make your code more elegant by using an array to map the month names.

```
 <script>
            var date = new Date();      // i get the date 
            var m = date.getMonth();    // i get the month
            var monthMap = ["January", "Febrauary", "Mar..", "Apr..", "May", "June", "July", "Aug..", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
            var d = date.getDate();      // the day
            var y = date.getFullYear();
            //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= monthMap[m] + " is the month, " + d + " is the Date(day) and "+ y + " is the full year"; 
            // i removed this ^ to highlight the new output below:
            document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= date + "<br>" + m + " - " + monthMap[m];
        </script>
```

Replace Aug... with August and other necessary month names

Comment: That alone wouldn't fix their bug. There's also the fact that the else statement setting fm to Error01 runs if the month isn't December instead of if it isn't any of the months.

Answer (score 3):

You keep changing the value of m and fm in your code:

```
if (m=0){fm="January";}
...
if (m=11){fm="December";}
```

...sets m to zero, then to one, then to two... The last one to run is m=11 and fm to December, which will always happen.

Change your = to == in your if statements to fix.  And remove the else, use else if correctly, or use a switch (the else as written only applies to the LAST if clause).

See the section on else if [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code. The first is that you're assigning variables instead of testing them in your if statements.

```
if(m=0){fm="January"}
```

The above is wrong because you're saying `m = 0`, and then the if statement runs because `m = 0` is parsed into `m` which is 0, meaning that yes, variable `m` exists, so the if condition is true and the code runs. This continues until the last one, where it has the value of 11, and so fm =  'December'.

The second problem is that the last condition, which is *supposed* to check to see if the month is a valid value, and if it isn't it says so in an obvious way, doesn't actually do that.

```
else {fm="Error01"}
```

The else statement is running when the month isn't December, because it's only connected to the December if statement. By making all of the if statements after the first else if statements, we can fix this problem, and make your original code work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="test"></p>               // this is where date will be displayed
    <script>
        var date = new Date();      // i get the date 
        var m = date.getMonth();    // i get the month
        var fm;                     // all this is to convert number to month name
        if (m===0){fm="January";}
        else if (m===1){fm="February";}
        else if (m===2){fm="March";}
        else if (m===3){fm="April";}
        else if (m===4){fm="May";}
        else if (m===5){fm="Jun";}
        else if (m===6){fm="July";}
        else if (m===7){fm="August";}
        else if (m===8){fm="September";}
        else if (m===9){fm="October";}
        else if (m===10){fm="November";}
        else if (m===11){fm="December";}
        else {fm="Error01"}console.log(fm)
        var d = date.getDate();      // the day
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= fm + " is the month, " + d + " is the Date(day) and "+ y + " is the full year"; 
        // i removed this ^ to highlight the new output below:
        //document.getElementById("test").innerHTML= date + "<br>" + m + " - " + fm;
      //the above code has completed tests properly, and so has been replaced by the original code
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```